# Is it ok to use "chip in" like this in an IELTS writing task

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary, logic

I want to express that the purpose of education should serve the development of whole society.

My writing:

> On one hand, in most countries, education is invested with national revenue. In other words, every tax payer is required to chip in. So, it should serve for the development of whole society.

My question:

1. is "chip in" too informal? Should I change it?
2. are these three sentences logical to a native speaker of English?

Comment: As far as I know, IELTS writing should be written in formal English. ‘Chip in’ is too informal for that task. However, you can use it in IELTS speaking as that is an informal conversation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yeah I leant the phrase "chip in" from a TV sitcom, so I was worried that it is not proper to use in IELTS writing. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly informal, I would likely just use 'contribute'.

And note that in the US for example it isn't necessarily true. Many school districts are funded from property taxes rather than more general revenue sources.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then I think I'd better say "in my country...".